# Найти значение между скобках и проверить их затем заменить JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения

мне нужно узнать значение между скобками и если значение больше 100 изменить его на 100.
Я пытался что-то до сделать но у меня не вышло, вот примерный код:

```
if("(101)".match(/\((.+?)\)/)) return "(100)"
```

UPD: спасибо всем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
function fix(str) {
  const number = parseInt(str.match(/\((\d+\))/)[1], 10);
  if (number > 100) return '(100)';
  return str;
}

console.log(fix('(99)'));
console.log(fix('(100)'));
console.log(fix('(101)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерный ответ =)
`if("(101)".match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1] > 100) return "(100)"`

Comment: сравнивать строку с числом - не очень правильно.

Comment: Я страюсь дать ответ максимально близкий к вопросу, так на мой взгляд будет легче понять ответ. А вот хуже всего тут, ````match(//)[n]````, сколько радости ````null```` доставит :D